# Rpi can't see external hard drive

Tags: usb, linux, hard-drive, osmc

I got stacked. I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with OSMC installed on it. I want to connect an external drive (Seagate Backup Plus 1TB) to it.

I connected it through a usb hub and there is an additional power source connected to RPi. But my RPi can't see the hard drive.

If I type `sudo fdisk -l` I get:

```
Device         Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        2048  499711  497664  243M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      501760 3854335 3352576  1.6G 83 Linux
```

As you can see there is no Seagate hard drive.

What am I supposed to do?

dmesg:

```
[ 3720.753243] usb 1-1.4.3: new full-speed USB device number 12 using dwc_otg
[ 3720.859765] usb 1-1.4.3: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[ 3720.869524] usb 1-1.4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab21
[ 3720.869558] usb 1-1.4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3720.869576] usb 1-1.4.3: Product: BUP Slim BK
[ 3720.869591] usb 1-1.4.3: Manufacturer: Seagate
[ 3720.869607] usb 1-1.4.3: SerialNumber: NA7805B4
[ 3720.871294] usb-storage 1-1.4.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3720.873274] usb-storage 1-1.4.3:1.0: Quirks match for vid 0bc2 pid ab21: 2000000
[ 3720.881189] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.4.3:1.0
[ 3721.886536] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim BK      0143 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3721.888811] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 3721.896262] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[ 3727.383243] ....................
[ 3747.558453] usb 1-1.4.3: USB disconnect, device number 12
```

Comment: What does, "0 down vote favorite I got stacked" mean?

Comment: What does dmesg report when you plug the drive into a USB port?

Comment: How exactly is the Pi powered? Is the USB hub powered?  Does the drive work with any other computer? And what does I got stacked mean?

Comment: The Pi is powered by usb hub: by micro usb, USB hub is powered, drive doesn't work with any other computer. "I got stacked" -- I'm not good in english. I wanted to say that I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: My guess would be not enough power as the drive can't spin to speed.

Comment: I suspect from your wording that the hub is unpowered, and hence the drive is powered by the Pi - even though it is plugged into a hub. I would try it with another computer to rule out drive issues first though.

Comment: Steve Robillard, the hub can't be unpowered, because Pi is powered by hub.

Comment: Then what does this mean "an additional power source connected to RPi"? Also, a USB hub may not supply enough current to reliably power the Pi.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your dmesg output, it looks like the hard drive isn't getting enough power.  It's does the connection phase, and then starts the spin up process.  Since this is the most energy intensive task, it makes sense that it would be the point at which the connection fails.

I would suggest switching to a powered USB hub.

**Edit:**

Based on your comments:

> the drive doesn't work with any other computer

and

> USB hub is powered

we can reasonably surmise that the drive has a mechanical issue, and that this isn't a problem with the RPi at all.

**Edit 2:**

Based on a clarifying comment:

> If I connect the hard drive through usb-hub to other computers, it doesn't work, but if I connect it without hub, it works.

We're back to the power issue.  Your eHDD will require a certain amount of power, just like the RPi does.  The back of the drive should list its requirements.  Check what the powered hub supports, and what the power supply is giving the hub.

Comment: If I connect the hard drive through usb-hub to other computers, it doesn't work, but if I connect it without hub, it works.

Comment: @GlebVishnevsky: Then we're back to the power supply issue.  What is the maximum output of the powered USB hub? How much are you supply it with? Remember the RPi needs a **minimum** of 700mA, then your drive will need power as well.

Comment: Does the hub work? Does the drive work when powered by the Pi note the Pi should not be powered by a hub (especially this one that is perhaps not working correctly/fully)?

Comment: USB hub is not powered by an external power source. You need a powered USB hub